# Python list value usage

Tags: python, list

Hello from a python newbe

I want to calculate some physical values. Therefore I have package loaded which works. I can use it with single values. But I do not only have single values, I have 100 of values, in two list. 
I want to calculate with given pressures and a temperatures the enthalpy. So I have two list, one for the pressure values one for the temperature values. I want to use them both in the package pyXSteam.

Here is my idea:

```
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 
T_ein= [398,397,396] #°C
P_ein=[29,27,26] #bara
Hin = steamTable.h_pt(P_ein,T_ein)
```

However, I don't understand how I give the two values form the lists (pressure, temperature - for testing I only used 3 values) to calculate the steamTable values. Can somebody explain me how to do this?

Thank you
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking to loop through two lists at the same time. The zip() function should do what you need:

```
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam

steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 
T_ein= [398,397,396] #°C
P_ein=[29,27,26] #bara

Hin = []  # Declare a list
for t, p in zip(T_ein, P_ein):
    Hin.append(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein,T_ein))
    print(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein,T_ein)) # Comment out

print(Hin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyXSteam.XSteam import XSteam
steamTable = XSteam(XSteam.UNIT_SYSTEM_MKS) 
T_ein = [398, 397, 396]
P_ein = [29, 27, 26]
Hin = []

for i in range(len(T_ein)):
    Hin.append(steamTable.h_pt(P_ein[i],T_ein[i]))

print(Hin)
```

Which will give you result as : 
`[3228.718854742986, 3229.858248382559, 3229.3075222556217]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It runs! :-)

Comment: @THZ You can give up-arrow to those answers which you found useful, This can help others to identify and refer these useful answers.